# PostgreSql migration error

Tags: asp.net, postgresql, aspnetboilerplate

I have aspnet zero project and trying to use it with the **Postgresql**. I followed the instructions and when i tried to `Update-Database` it gaves me error:

> Failed executing DbCommand (18ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', 
>       CommandTimeout='30']
>       CREATE SEQUENCE "AppSubscriptionPayments_Id_seq" START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 
>       NO MINVALUE NO MAXVALUE NO CYCLE;
>       ALTER TABLE "AppSubscriptionPayments" ALTER COLUMN "Id" TYPE int8;
>       ALTER TABLE "AppSubscriptionPayments" ALTER COLUMN "Id" SET NOT NULL;
>       ALTER TABLE "AppSubscriptionPayments" ALTER COLUMN "Id" SET DEFAULT 
>       (nextval('"AppSubscriptionPayments_Id_seq"'));
>       ALTER SEQUENCE "AppSubscriptionPayments_Id_seq" OWNED BY 
>       "AppSubscriptionPayments"."Id"
>
> 42P01: "AppSubscriptionPayments" object is not exists

I'm Using Postgresql 10, Visual Studio 2017 and ASPNET Zero.

Comment: You can delete the DB and run `Update-Database`. It will 100% work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Delete all existing migrations and Add-Migration from scratch.
- Be sure there's not an existing database (that specified in the connection string) while you add-migrations. If you have an already created database before, migrations cannot be built correctly.

https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/EF-Core-PostgreSql-Integration

Comment: Like I said I already did it. Somehow my colleague makes it work after getting this error and we are not sure how he accomplished. My problem still exists.

Comment: ok,found my problem. "Remove migration classes". I didn't remove ContextModelSnapshot.cs file and that is the problem. Documentation may be updated like this: "Remove migration classes = Remove-Migration" , Thanks for help.